# Youtube Api update publishAt TypeError python

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api

I tried to update my videos publishing date via youtube api bu i get TypeError. I didn't understand why i get this error. I thought it may be because of date format so i tried to datetime instead of "2020-2-5T20:00:00.00+03:00" but outcomes didn't changed. Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    date = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 5, 20, 00)

    request = youtube.videos().update(
        body={
            "id": 'D5sSw6Xqu34',
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "private",
                "publishAt": "2020-2-5T20:00:00.00+03:00"
            }
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/erkan/Desktop/uppo/tekli.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/erkan/Desktop/uppo/tekli.py", line 36, in main
    "publishAt": '2020-2-5T20:00:00.00+03:00',
  File "C:\Users\erkan\Desktop\uppo\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 731, in method
    raise TypeError('Missing required parameter "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Missing required parameter "part"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `2020-2-5T20:00:00.00+03:00` - a few zeroes are missing. It should be: `2020-02-05T20:00:00.00+03:00`.

Comment: Just with a quick glance, I believe the correct key is "publishedAt" instead of "publishAt". But I'm not sure if that's the primary error. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Comment: Also, as far as the format goes, you can view what other videos look like when hitting the rss-feed. You'll see:

<published>2020-01-30T16:48:32+00:00</published>
<updated>2020-01-30T16:53:33+00:00</updated>

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCBcRF18a7Qf58cCRy5xuWwQ

Comment: I figured out how to do it mates. I forgot "part" section at request. ‍♂️

Comment: @rknksy HA! we've all been there. Thanks for posting an update.