# Why is publishAt in YouTube API not working?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I'm trying to schedule a video to be published via the YouTube API using the `video.update` method and the `status.publishAt` parameter.
But I get an error - 400.

> The request metadata specifies an invalid scheduled publishing time.

I'm giving the time in the correct format but still getting the error. What can be wrong?
I also used the datetime library. And there I formatted the time in ISO format. But the error still occurs.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

```
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
client_secrets_file = 'client_secret.json'
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

# get upload playlist id
request = youtube.channels().list(
    part="contentDetails",
    mine=True
)
response = request.execute()
uploads = response["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]

# get all uploaded videos
request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    part="snippet,contentDetails,status",
    playlistId=uploads,
    maxResults=50,
)
response = request.execute()
allvids = response["items"]

while "nextPageToken" in response.keys():
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,status",
        playlistId=uploads,
        maxResults=50,
        pageToken=response["nextPageToken"]
    )
    response = request.execute()
    allvids += response["items"]

# identify only private videos
privvids = [vid for vid in allvids if vid["status"]["privacyStatus"] == "private"]

# let's publish the oldest uploaded draft
vid = privvids[-1]

snippet = vid["snippet"]
# modify snippet as needed

# note that you must set a categoryId if updating the snippet
snippet["categoryId"] = 27  # this is education

# change status to public
status = vid["status"]
status["privacyStatus"] = "private"
status["selfDeclaredMadeForKids"] = False
status["publishAt"] = '2022-12-29T02:00:00.000Z'
# apply changes
response = youtube.videos().update(
    part='snippet,status',
    body=dict(
        snippet=snippet,
        status=status,
        id=snippet["resourceId"]["videoId"]
    )).execute()
```

Comment: '2022-12-29T02:01:07.000Z' - example

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @Alderven I added. Look please.

Comment: @АлесандрМерсер can you try change the date as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60062547/12511801)? - in your case, would be like: `"2022-12-29T00:00:00+02:00"`

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes yes, I tried. I changed only the day, from 29 to 30.
But still the same error.

Comment: @АлесандрМерсер then, please post your question as a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) - there is something missing and they might help you.